# Best resource to learn Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

What is the best resource about Spring MVC that lets you get a grip on the framework and teaches best practices to create robust and maintainable applications?

On the web I found a lot of examples and tutorials, which hardly ever explain the magic happening in the back.

I am happy about any recommendation (book, web site, blog) that teaches best practices and higher level concepts about SpringMVC.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would start with the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/).  Specifically:

- [Web MVC framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) documentation
- [Getting Started with Spring MVC](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/01/04/green-beans-getting-started-with-spring-mvc/) from the springsource blog